# how to extract date present in dd-mon-yyyy format from string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in an `Oracle` table:

```
.31244
abc
10-oct-2013
10-oct-13
60
```

I want to write a query to get the following output via `Regex`:

```
10-oct-2013
10-oct-13
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything? Or you just need some free code?

Comment: Thanks SVK i have tried this query:-                                SELECT * from  test
where REGEXP_LIKE (mystring, '[0-30]-[a-z][A-Z]-[:digit:]')

Comment: so add it to you question, always put all the info there

Comment: Sure SVK please help me out if you have any idea on this.

Comment: btw do you realize your regex has to be ready for leap years, and soo? Its pretty difficult. Maybe a better solution would be to use to_date in some stored procedure - for example first with `'dd-mon-yyyy'`, in case of exception with `dd-mon-yy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this expression:

```
'[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:alpha:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{2}','i'
```

**please try this fiddle:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9dd8c/5

Answer (score 1):

Simple try:

```
with w(item) as
(
  select '.31244' from dual
  union all
  select 'abc' from dual
  union all
  select '10-oct-2013' from dual
  union all
  select '10-oct-13' from dual
  union all
  select '60' from dual
)
select item, case when regexp_substr(item, '\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}') is not null then to_date(item, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
                  when regexp_substr(item, '\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2}') is not null then to_date(item, 'dd-mon-yy')
                  end conv_date
from w
;
```

This gives:

```
ITEM        CONV_DATE
.31244      null
abc         null
10-oct-2013 10-oct.-2013
10-oct-13   10-oct.-2013
60          null
```